# Sorting alphanumeric hash keys in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting

Given the following hash:

```perl
%errors = (
    "2013-W9 -> 2013-W12" => 1,
    "2013-W5 -> 2013-W8" => 1,
    "2013-W13 -> 2013-W15" => 1
)
```

I'm trying to sort it like this (so I can use it in a `foreach` loop):

```perl
%errors = (
    "2013-W5 -> 2013-W8" => 1,
    "2013-W9 -> 2013-W12" => 1,
    "2013-W13 -> 2013-W15" => 1
)
```

I've tried `sort keys %errors` and `sort{$a <=> $b) keys %errors` without success.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Will you be seeing other letters in these keys? Such as `2013-X12`?

Comment: how is it sorting the hash when you call sort keys %errors on it?

Comment: Yes, I might see other letters as well, like M for month. W is for week by the way.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that in this case the CPAN module `Sort::Naturally` works fine:

```
use Sort::Naturally qw(nsort);
say $_ for nsort keys %errors;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what sort order you want, but this approach can easily be extended:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %errors = (
    "2013-W9 -> 2013-W12" => 1,
    "2013-W5 -> 2013-W8" => 1,
    "2013-W13 -> 2013-W15" => 1
);

my @sorted_keys = map { $_->[0] }
  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
  map  { [ $_, /W(\d+)/ ] } keys %errors;

say $_ for @sorted_keys;
```

Answer (score 2):

At *[The Alphanum Algorithm](http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html)* there's a general string sort routine that compares numeric substrings as numbers, implemented in many languages including Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Keys will be sorted for `yyyy-Wx` in ascending order; first by comparing `yyyy` and then `x` numbers,

```
my @sorted_keys = map $_->[0],
  sort {
    $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]
    ||
    $a->[2] <=> $b->[2]
  }
  map [ $_, /(\d+)/g ],
  keys %errors;
```

Comment: Perhaps I need more coffee... isn't that correct then? 9 is less than 13. But on the other hand, it might mess up subsequent numberings, such as hmm... `2013-1 -> 2013-99` vs `2013-10 -> 2013-1`

Comment: I guess the correct way would be to pad numbers with zeros in that case, so that `9` -> `09`. And then you would have to know how long the max length was, and you would have to make sure not to exceed the max integer size (in case of very long strings). Perhaps your original way is the simpler option after all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of situation. I solved my problem in the below way:

You tried with

```
sort keys %errors
```

and

```
sort{$a <=> $b) keys %errors
```

Just try almost a similar thing with a little difference:

#### Code:

```
my %errors = (
    "2013-W9 -> 2013-W12" => 1,
    "2013-W5 -> 2013-W8" => 1,
    "2013-W13 -> 2013-W15" => 1);

foreach my $val(sort {my ($anum) = ($a =~ /\d+-\w(\d+)$/);  my ($bnum) = ($b =~ /\d+-\w(\d+)$/);  $anum <=> $bnum} keys %error
{
    print "$val\n";
}
```

In the above example I have printed the keys only.

**Output:**

```
2013-W5 -> 2013-W8
2013-W9 -> 2013-W12
2013-W13 -> 2013-W15
```