# Sort an array in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I have an array with elements

```
@a =(mem_64x128,mem_8x64,mem_8x128,mem_128x64);
```

I want the array to be sorted in the following manner

```
   mem_8x64,mem_8x128,mem_64x128,mem_128x64
```

But when I `sort @a`, the output I get is

```
mem_128x64
mem_64x128
mem_8x64
mem_8x128
```

Can anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: It is because when sorting alphabetically `128` comes before `64`. You might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19544253/725418

Comment: But how can I do this for an array?

Comment: The same way. You sort a list of elements, not a data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another use case where the `nsort` function from the CPAN module `Sort::Naturally` works as humans expect it:

```
@a =(mem_64x128,mem_8x64,mem_8x128,mem_128x64); # no strict!
use Sort::Naturally qw(nsort);
print join(',', nsort @a), "\n";
```

Output is:

```
mem_8x64,mem_8x128,mem_64x128,mem_128x64
```

Answer (score 4):

Use custom comparing function [sort (perldoc)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html):

```
sort {
   my ($c,$d) = $a =~ /(\d+)x(\d+)/;
   my ($e,$f) = $b =~ /(\d+)x(\d+)/;
   $c<=>$e || $d<=>$f;
} @a;
```

or faster one:

```
my %h;
@a = sort  {
   $h{$a} || ( @{$h{$a}} = $a =~ /(\d+)x(\d+)/ );
   $h{$b} || ( @{$h{$b}} = $b =~ /(\d+)x(\d+)/ );
   $h{$a}->[0] <=> $h{$b}->[0] || $h{$a}->[1] <=> $h{$b}->[1];
} @a;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a =("mem_64x128","mem_8x64","mem_8x128","mem_128x64");

print sort byFirst sort bySecond @a;

sub byFirst{
# Extract first number from a
my $y=$a;
$y =~ s/.*_//;
$y =~ s/x.*//;

# Extract first number from b
my $z=$b;
$z =~ s/.*_//;
$z =~ s/x.*//;
return $y <=> $z;
}

sub bySecond{
# Extract second number from a
my $y=$a;
$y =~ s/.*x//;

# Extract second number from b
my $z=$b;
$z =~ s/.*x//;
return $y <=> $z;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;


my @a = ('mem_64x128', 'mem_8x64', 'mem_8x128', 'mem_128x64');

my @sorted_a = sort { (split /[_x]/, $a)[1] <=> (split /[_x]/, $b)[1]
                           or
          (split /[_x]/, $a)[2] <=> (split /[_x]/, $b)[2]
} @a;

print "$_\n" foreach @sorted_a;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
mem_8x64
mem_8x128
mem_64x128
mem_128x64
```

Comment: `/_|x/` is better written `/[_x]/`.

Comment: @TLP Thanks for the observation. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Elements are sorted by first, and second number in ascending order,

```
my @r = qw(mem_64x128 mem_8x64 mem_8x128 mem_128x64);

@r = map { $_->[0] }
  sort {
    $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[2] <=> $b->[2]
  }
  map { [$_, /(\d+)/g ] } @r;

print "@r\n";
```

output

```
mem_8x64 mem_8x128 mem_64x128 mem_128x64
```