# i have to sort based on second argument..in perl

Tags: perl

input:

```
EMP_T4_SHARED_IRQ_o,198
EMP_T5_SHARED_IRQ_o,199
EMP_T6_SHARED_IRQ_o,237
oDRF_LPINT2G_v4_main,201
```

output:

```
EMP_T4_SHARED_IRQ_o,198
EMP_T5_SHARED_IRQ_o,199
oDRF_LPINT2G_v4_main,201
EMP_T6_SHARED_IRQ_o,237
```

sort the text file based on second field in perl..

Comment: You should show what you tried, or use search, because some questions already have answers, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586800/sort-an-array-in-perl/. And welcome to SO

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -F',' -ane'
  push @r,[ $_, $F[1] ];
  END{ print map $_->[0], sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]} @r }
' input
```

or

```
perl -e'
  print
    map $_->[0], 
    sort{ $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map [$_, (split /,/)[1] ], <>;
' input
```

Comment: you give a really nice and concise answer, and I really impressed by your skill on perl

Comment: @JackXu tnx for your comment

Comment: I like a nice Schwartzian Transform :-)

Comment: @DaveCross I guess only second example qualify as ST? :)

Comment: Yes, but the first one is clearly influenced by the ST as well :)