# Sorting hash keys by Alphanumeric sort

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, alphanumeric

I have just read the post *[Sorting alphanumeric hash keys in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544253)*. But I am starting with Perl, and I don't understand it very clearly.

So I have a hash like this one:

```
  %hash = (
        "chr1" => 1,
        "chr2" => 3,
        "chr19" => 14,
        "chr22" => 1,
        "X" => 2,
    )
```

I'm trying to obtain output like this:

```
chr1
chr2
chr19
chr22
```

But I'm obtaining output like this:

```
chr1
chr19
chr2
chr22
```

I have written this code, but it is creating the above wrong output:

```
foreach my $chr (sort {$a cmp $b} keys(%hash)) {
    my $total= $hash{$chr};
    my $differentpercent= ($differenthash{$chr} / $total)*100;
    my $round=(int($differentpercent*1000))/1000;
    print "$chr\t$hash{$chr}\t$differenthash{$chr}\t$round\n";
}
```

It prints:

```
chr1    342421    7449    2.175
chr10    227648    5327    2.34
chr11    220415    4468    2.027
chr12    213263    4578    2.146
chr13    172379    3518    2.04
chr14    143534    2883    2.008
chr15    126441    2588    2.046
chr16    138239    3596    2.601
chr17    122137    3232    2.646
chr18    130275    3252    2.496
chr19    99876    2836    2.839
chr2    366815    8123    2.214
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update** Note @Miller's comment below on some shortcomings of the `Sort::Naturally` module.

What you are asking for is a relatively complicated sort that splits each string into alphabetical and numeric fields, and then sorts the letters lexically and the numbers by value.

The module [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/module/Sort::Naturally) will do what you ask, or you can write something like this. You appear to have ignored the `X` key, so I have sorted it to the end using a case-independent sort.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } qw(
    chr22  chr20  chr19  chr13  chr21  chr16  chr12  chr10  chr18
    chr17  chrY   chr5   chrX   chr8   chr14  chr6   chr3   chr9
    chr1   chrM   chr11  chr2   chr7   chr4   chr15
);

my @sorted_keys = sort {
    my @aa = $a =~ /^([A-Za-z]+)(\d*)/;
    my @bb = $b =~ /^([A-Za-z]+)(\d*)/;
    lc $aa[0] cmp lc $bb[0] or $aa[1] <=> $bb[1];
} keys %hash;

print "$_\n" for @sorted_keys;
```

**output**

```
chr1
chr2
chr3
chr4
chr5
chr6
chr7
chr8
chr9
chr10
chr11
chr12
chr13
chr14
chr15
chr16
chr17
chr18
chr19
chr20
chr21
chr22
chrM
chrX
chrY
```

Using the [`Sort::Naturally`](https://metacpan.org/module/Sort::Naturally) module (you will probably have to install it) you could write this instead.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Sort::Naturally;

my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } qw(
    chr22  chr20  chr19  chr13  chr21  chr16  chr12  chr10  chr18
    chr17  chrY   chr5   chrX   chr8   chr14  chr6   chr3   chr9
    chr1   chrM   chr11  chr2   chr7   chr4   chr15
);

my @sorted_keys = nsort keys %hash;

print "$_\n" for @sorted_keys;
```

The output is identical to the above.

Comment: @Borodin You intentionally chose not to do a [`Schwartzian transform`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) for speed efficiency.  This is probably an ok choice since I expect we're only dealing with on the order of 300 elements.  However, I find this curious because I've pretty much never see an expert not use an ST on perlmonks.  Is this a premature optimization that you will sometimes avoid in your live code as well?  Or just something avoided in an example like this because it enables the user to more easily see how to do the alternative sort?

Comment: @Miller: Absolutely. I always use the standard sort unless it has proved to be too slow. Even if I end up caching the sort keys (there are many ways to do this besides the ST) I usually leave the original sort code alongside to document what it's *really* doing, as it is far from immediately obvious what is being sorted in a Schwartzian Transform.

Comment: @Borodin I would strongly recommend switching this module recommendation to [`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural).  There are bugs in `Sort::Naturally` where it ignores punctuation and only looks for alternation between letters and number groups.  For example for this data `qw(124:8 17:11);`, it will sort 124 before 17, because internally it strips the colon and then sorts them numerically as a single number.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be solved with a common Perl idiom called [map-sort-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
   "chr1"  => 1,
   "chr2"  => 3,
   "chr19" => 14,
   "chr22" => 1,
);

my @sorted = map  { $_->[0]             }
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
             map  { [$_, (/chr(\d+)/) || 0]  } keys %hash;

print Dumper \@sorted;
__END__
[
  'chr1',
  'chr2',
  'chr19',
  'chr22'
];
```

Note: Unlike @Borodin I chose sort X to the front because it wasn't specified so I just choose an end.

Comment: No, your solution doesn't sort to the front by choice: you simply didn't cater for it. Adding that element to the hash makes your solution throw three `Use of uninitialized value` warnings. And there is no reason to transform the data in this case: it just makes the code less intelligible.

Comment: @Borodin It didn't before I edited in a default case.

Comment: It still doesnt sort alphanumerically though, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

This has been the way I've been doing it for the longest time... I'm stealing the code from Borodin's post for reference. Borodin's sort code is very simple to follow if you understand regex.  I prefer putting complicated sorts into a sub because it really gets messy otherwise. Anyway here you go:

```
my %hash = (
    "chr1" => 1,
    "chr2" => 3,
    "chr19" => 14,
    "chr22" => 1,
    "X" => 2,
);

foreach my $key (sort {&sortalphanum} keys %hash)
{
  print "  $key = $hash{$key}\n";
}

sub sortalphanum
{
  my @aa = $a =~ /^([A-Za-z]+)(\d*)/;
  my @bb = $b =~ /^([A-Za-z]+)(\d*)/;
  lc $aa[0] cmp lc $bb[0] or $aa[1] <=> $bb[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my %records;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($key, undef) = split;
    $records{$key} = $_;
}

my @keys = sort {
    my ($aa) = $a =~ /(\d+)/;
    my ($bb) = $b =~ /(\d+)/;
    $aa <=> $bb;
} keys %records;

foreach my $key (@keys) {
    printf "$records{$key}";
}


__DATA__
chr1    342421  7449    2.175
chr10   227648  5327    2.34
chr11   220415  4468    2.027
chr12   213263  4578    2.146
chr13   172379  3518    2.04
chr14   143534  2883    2.008
chr15   126441  2588    2.046
chr16   138239  3596    2.601
chr17   122137  3232    2.646
chr18   130275  3252    2.496
chr19   99876   2836    2.839
chr2    366815  8123    2.214
```

---

Output:

```
$ perl t01.pl 
chr1    342421  7449    2.175
chr2    366815  8123    2.214
chr10   227648  5327    2.34
chr11   220415  4468    2.027
chr12   213263  4578    2.146
chr13   172379  3518    2.04
chr14   143534  2883    2.008
chr15   126441  2588    2.046
chr16   138239  3596    2.601
chr17   122137  3232    2.646
chr18   130275  3252    2.496
chr19   99876   2836    2.839
```

Comment: It is not working, it prints:

chrY
chrX
chrM
chr7
chr20
chr22
chr14
chr8
chr19
chr1
chr6
chr11
chr17
chr21
chr16
chr18
chr3
chr12
chr15
chr4
chr2
chr9
chr13
chr10
chr5

Comment: @userbio: You have listed strings there that you didn't put in your question. It is important to describe the *full range* of values that you expect, otherwise proposed solutions won't work.