# How to sort perl hash keys

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have a hash which looks like this

```
my %hash = (
    '124:8' => '',
    '4:2'   => '',
    '17:11' => '',
    '17:0'  => '',
    #and so on
);
```

I tried to sort and use hash keys by small number to bigger

```
for my $keys ( sort { $a > $b } keys %hash ) {
    #do stuff
}
```

This gives me some result that looks like correct but it fails sometimes. I don't know how to compare both numbers, `124:8` with `4:2` since it has `:` in a middle, any suggestions ?

Comment: Your question has been asked and answered before here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22300539/725418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to sort on first and second number delimited by `:`

```
my @sorted = sort {
  my ($aa, $bb) =  map [ split /:/ ], $a, $b;
  $aa->[0] <=> $bb->[0] || $aa->[1] <=> $bb->[1]

} keys %hash;

for my $key (@sorted) { .. }
```

Using Schwartzian,

```
my @sorted = map $_->[0],
sort {
  $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[2] <=> $b->[2]
}
map [ $_, split /:/ ],
keys %hash;
```

Answer (score 4):

When you sort numbers, you use the `<=>` operator:

```
for my $key (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash) {
```

This operator returns 1, 0 or -1 depending on the comparison. `>` only returns true or false, which explains it working with some results, but not all.

Because your keys are not numbers, they will only partially convert to numbers, and you will get warnings

```
Argument "17:11" isn't numeric in sort
```

Then you will need to use something like [`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural), or swing your own, such as:

```
sort {
    my @a = $a =~ /\d+/g;
    my @b = $b =~ /\d+/g;
    $a[0] <=> $b[0] ||
    $a[1] <=> $b[1]    # continue as long as needed
} keys %hash
```

You may also use a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to cache the numbers and possibly speed up the sort.

Or just sort by string comparison, though this will cause `17:11` to end up after `17:2`.

Comment: oops, this is awesome but still have a bug, it prints `17:11` before `17:0`

Comment: That is because those are strings and not numbers. They get converted to numbers by Perl, and both become 17. You need to separate the number parts, or use a natural sort module.

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as above solutions, but what to convert the `:` to `.` and compare them as floating point numbers? Because no math operations occurs, no rounding errors and the next *could* work:

```
my %tmp = map { (my $x = $_) =~ s/:/./; $_,$x} keys %hash;
my @sortedkeys =  sort { $tmp{$a} <=> $tmp{$b} } keys %tmp;
#4:2 17:0 17:11 124:8
```

Or this approach is wrong?