# Sort keys in hashes which contains alphanumeric using perl

Tags: perl, hash

How to sort the Keys from hashes (In keys there is `alphaNumeric` contains in the hashes) and **print the hashes as an output**.

```
 %bibIdstr = (
      'bib16' => 'newbib12',
      'bib7' => 'newbib6',
      'bib11' => 'newbib9',
      'bib4' => 'newbib4',
      'bib2' => 'newbib2',
      'bib1' => 'newbib1',
      'bib18' => 'newbib13',
      'bib13' => 'newbib10',
      'bib14' => 'newbib11',
      'bib10' => 'newbib8',
      'bib8' => 'newbib7',
      'bib6' => 'newbib5',
      'bib3' => 'newbib3'
    );
```

My Code:

```
foreach my $keys (sort (keys %bibIdstr))
{
    print $keys ."->". $bibIdstr{$keys} . "\n";
}
```

Its printing output below

```
bib1->newbib1
bib10->newbib8
bib11->newbib9
bib13->newbib10
bib14->newbib11
bib16->newbib12
bib18->newbib13
bib2->newbib2
bib3->newbib3
bib4->newbib4
bib6->newbib5
bib7->newbib6
bib8->newbib7
```

But my expected output is:

```
bib1->newbib1
bib2->newbib2
bib3->newbib3
bib4->newbib4
bib6->newbib5
bib7->newbib6
bib8->newbib7
bib10->newbib8
bib11->newbib9
bib13->newbib10
bib14->newbib11
bib16->newbib12
bib18->newbib13
```

It would be appreciated if someone could help on this one.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain how this is duplicate while comparing the with the already asked question. This is in hash variable and that is array variable. I don't know how to get the output from arrays to hashes.

Comment: Hint: put `keys %bibIdstr` into an array and sort it. Also you might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544253/sorting-alphanumeric-hash-keys-in-perl

Comment: Check out `Sort::Naturally`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
%bibIdstr = (
      'bib16' => 'newbib12',
      'bib7' => 'newbib6',
      'bib11' => 'newbib9',
      'bib4' => 'newbib4',
      'bib2' => 'newbib2',
      'bib1' => 'newbib1',
      'bib18' => 'newbib13',
      'bib13' => 'newbib10',
      'bib14' => 'newbib11',
      'bib10' => 'newbib8',
      'bib8' => 'newbib7',
      'bib6' => 'newbib5',
      'bib3' => 'newbib3'
    );

sub sortByNumber($$){
my      $a = shift;
my      $b = shift;
        $a =~ s/bib//;
        $b =~ s/bib//;

        return $a <=> $b;
}

foreach my $keys (sort {sortByNumber($a,$b) }(keys %bibIdstr))
{
    print $keys ."->". $bibIdstr{$keys} . "\n";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
bib1->newbib1
bib2->newbib2
bib3->newbib3
bib4->newbib4
bib6->newbib5
bib7->newbib6
bib8->newbib7
bib10->newbib8
bib11->newbib9
bib13->newbib10
bib14->newbib11
bib16->newbib12
bib18->newbib13
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Thats for downvoting without explanation